# jQuery scroll To Element in a different php page

Tags: php, jquery, html, scroll

I have a href tag in reply.php file

```
<a id="click" href="javascript:replytoQuestion('<?=$comment_id?>')">Answer <?=htmlentities($row['studentname'])?> </a>
```

Then I have a form in index.php file

```
<form id="answerForm"
```

When user click Answer in href tag page must scroll to  form id="answerForm

I tried to use this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function (){
        $("#click").click(function (){
            //$(this).animate(function(){
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#answer").offset().top
                }, 2000);
            //});
        });
    });
</script>
```

but it does not work.

Any suggestions

Comment: So are you leaving the page, if so show us the replytoQuestion() function, as that is a lot more interesting than what you're doing to scroll the page you're leaving ?

Comment: @Dev'Hamz Sorry #click should be in <a id="click" href=javascript I will edit my code above

Comment: Again, this is all completely irrelevant until you post the replytoQuestion() function

Comment: @adeno function replytoQuestion(id){
            document.getElementById('inReplyTo').value = id;

            //May be I can write a code to scroll down to comment to answer box here. I am not sure how to write it
        }
    </script>

Comment: You can use an anchor in your function replytoQuestion with a smootheffect using jQuery.

Comment: I still don't get it, so you're not leaving the page, but how do you intend to scroll in index.php when something is clicked in reply.php ?

Comment: @Dev'Hamz I am kind of new. Can you show me a how to do that?

Comment: @Dev'Hamz I am trying your suggestion. I think that is the answer

Comment: @adeno Thanks for your question. It help me to think about the javascript function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happy that it worked, my idea was pretty simple :

```
function replytoQuestion(numberId, idName) {
     var numberId; // Number id
     // *** Some treatment with numberId *** //
     return go(idName);
}

function go(idName) {
    // *** scroll to the div with smootheffect *** //
}
```